# Compiling React Typescript module for NPM

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, sass

I am trying to build & publish my first NPM module and have some questions about best practice when compiling. The project is a React component written in Typescript and using SASS.

My component works as it should when I import the index.ts directly into a test file and bundle the whole thing with webpack. However, if I bundle it I loose all the niceness of the Typings when importing into another project but if I try to use the compiled JS without bundling I have been getting errors resolving various assets including SCSS/CSS files and JSON files.

I know it's a rather large question but I've been unable to find a really good answer as to how I should be structuring the project. I've noticed a few thing from looking at other packages: 
- build/dist folders generally contain a bundled js file
- lib folders generally contain js files and typings and sometimes map files

So, the question I have is how to the bundles and compiled js files relate to each other and how should I be setting up my compilers to get it working.

I've been playing with webpack and tsc but can't seem to get the combination working. The latest issue I am having is that the compiled JS in my dist folder complains that it can't resolve the module.scss files which is correct as the scss was compiled to css using node-sass but clearly the references haven't updated properly. The bundle works when I use webpack but looses typings when importing into another project.

My TSCONFIG looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    //"rootDir": "src",
    "jsx": "react",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*", "temp"]
}
```

and I'm using the following script to build the compiled JS:

```
"build":"tsc && node-sass --recursive --output dist --source-map true --source-map-contents src && cp -r ./src/schemas ./dist/"
```

The source is on github here: https://github.com/androidpage/json-form-builder

Apologies the project is a bit of a mess at the moment but the primary goal was to learn how to structure and compile a project thus this question :)

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: *"module": "commonjs"* - since it's client-side lib, CommonJS is not enoug, you'll need to bundle the lib to UMD, so Webpack should be used. You could start with create-react-app and customize it if needed instead of trying to set up toolchain manually.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I didn't use create-react-app because I wanted to learn about the toolchain and how to make it work from scratch :) In any case I will keep tinkering for the moment and see what I can make work! I will go and examine a create-react-app project though and see if I can work backwards! Cheers!!

Comment: CRA config is quite convoluted if you're unfamiliar with Webpack and other tools. I'd suggest to start with browsing starter/boilerplate projects for the technologies you're after, i.e. Webpack+Typescript+SCSS.